# Error updating Flutter project: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "webview_flutter_wkwebview"

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, webview-flutter, webview-flutter-wkwebview

When attempting to update my Flutter project to a new Flutter version, I encountered the following error related to CocoaPods and the `webview_flutter_wkwebview` plugin:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "webview_flutter_wkwebview":
  In Podfile:
    webview_flutter_wkwebview (from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `webview_flutter_wkwebview (from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by adjusting the minimum deployment target in the Podfile.

The `webview_flutter_wkwebview` pod required a higher iOS deployment target than was previously set. Here are the steps I followed to resolve the error:

1. **Open the iOS Podfile**: Navigate to the `ios` folder of your Flutter project and open the `Podfile` in a text editor.
2. **Update the iOS Deployment Target**: Change the line `platform :ios, '9.0'` (or whatever your current version is) to `platform :ios, '12.0'`. This sets the minimum deployment target to `iOS 12.0`, which is compatible with the `webview_flutter_wkwebview` requirements.
3. **Save the Podfile**: After making the adjustment, save your changes to the Podfile.
4. **Run** `pod install`: Open a terminal, navigate to the `ios` directory of your project, and execute `pod install` to update the CocoaPods dependencies with your new settings.
5. **Clean and Rebuild Your Project**: It's a good practice to clean your project and rebuild it. Execute `flutter clean` followed by `flutter build ios` in your project's root directory.